# Android AsyncTask progress update hang

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

So I had a crack at coding my own AsyncTask class like system that runs on a ThreadPoolExecutor natively. Everything was working fine until I decided to implement the progress side of things. The progress works much like `AsyncTask`, the `onProgressUpdate` function is called on the UI thread. The problem I'm experiencing is that whenever there is a System.out or Log.x line in the onProgressUpdate it hangs indefinitely with no error or warning oddly. The code is as below:

```
 public abstract class Task<A, B> {

    private static final Executor EXECUTOR = getExecutor();
    private static final int DEFAULT_PRIORITY = Thread.MIN_PRIORITY;
    private static final int DEFAULT_PROGRESS_INCREMENT = 1;

    private static final Executor getExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(false);
        // TODO set rejection handler
        //executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new Handler());
        // TODO set thread factory
        executor.prestartCoreThread();
        return executor;
    }

    public static class ExecutionListener<B> {

        public void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("TASK", "Pre - Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        public void onPostExecute(B output) {

            Log.i("TASK", "Post - Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - Output: " + output);
        }

        public void onProgressUpdate(int progress) {
            Log.d("TASK", "Hello");
        }
    }

    private Handler handler;
    private ExecutionListener<B> executionListener;
    private volatile int progress = 0;
    private AtomicBoolean progressPublished = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    private B output;

    public Task() {
        this.handler = new Handler();
        this.executionListener = new ExecutionListener();
    }

    public void setExecutionListener(ExecutionListener executionListener) {
        if(executionListener == null) {
            this.executionListener = new ExecutionListener();
        }
        else {
            this.executionListener = executionListener;
        }
    }

    protected void updateProgress(int progressMade) {
        Log.d("TASK", "Test");
        progress += progressMade;
        if(progressPublished.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            if(!handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("TASK", new Integer(progress).toString() + " - a");
                    executionListener.onProgressUpdate(progress);
                    // Hangs below
                    progressPublished.lazySet(true);
                    Log.d("TASK", new Integer(progress).toString() + " - b");
                }
            })) {
                Log.d("TASK", "Failed to post");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void updateProgress() {
        updateProgress(DEFAULT_PROGRESS_INCREMENT);
    }

    protected abstract B doTask(A input);

    public void execute(final A input, final int priority) {
        EXECUTOR.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread().setPriority(priority);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        executionListener.onPreExecute();
                    }
                });
                output = doTask(input);
                if(!handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("TASK", "Done");
                        executionListener.onPostExecute(output);
                    }
                })) {
                    Log.d("TASK", "Failed to post post");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void execute(final A input) {
        execute(input, DEFAULT_PRIORITY);
    }
}
```

The `ExecutionListener` is just a class to override the methods to be run on the UI much like AsyncTask's methods for doing the same. The code uses Runnable objects to execute the doTask method and send updates / the result to the appropriate method in the ExecutionListener.

The `Thread.currentThread()` parts are just to ensure things are running on the thread I intended them to. The problem only shows itself when running a Task that frequently calls `updateProgress()` - I have tried putting a thread sleep in the `onProgressUpdate()` method and that seems so solve things, though that obviously isn't a good solution.

It also only seems to have a problem with Log.x / System.out - I don't know whether the call frequency of either of them could cause this kind of issue. I'm at a loss with this progress feature and logging so any advice would be greatly appreciated - I've also found this quite hard to explain so please ask if you need me to clarify anything!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Thread.currentThread().getId() is at fault. Removing that part fixes everything. Follow up question here: [Is Java Thread getId() thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371810/is-java-thread-getid-thread-safe)