# Is Java Thread getId() thread-safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

As the question title says, is `Thread.getId()` thread-safe? I recently had a problem whilst multithreading and the solution was to remove the `getId()` call as it was making the thread hang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely thread-safe. The full implementation in JDK8 is:

```
public long getId() {
    return tid;
}
```

`tid` is initialized once during construction of the `Thread` object and never changed afterward.

If there was a problem in your code that removing it solved, it was what you were *doing* with the ID once you had it, not getting the ID.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: yes,

long answer: thread safe means protecting against race condition

```
/**
 * Returns the identifier of this Thread.  The thread ID is a positive
 * <tt>long</tt> number generated when this thread was created.
 * The thread ID is unique and remains unchanged during its lifetime.
 * When a thread is terminated, this thread ID may be reused.
 *
 * @return this thread's ID.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public long getId() {
    return tid;
}
```

as you see the method is not synchronized, and the `tid` is private and not final declared, **but** the `tid` is set in the private method `init` and is never changing after that, that makes the value of `tid` immutable making it as well thread-safe

Comment: So first you answer no, then delete it, and once I post you change your answer to yes and undelete it.

Comment: yes,  as a human an able to correct as much as I want/need my answers.... thanks for the comment :)

Comment: It would be good if you did due diligence **before** posting rather than after.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will consider that for the future!